# DecimalFormat: wrong digit after comma

Tags: java, format, decimal, decimalformat

i have a problem with DecimalFormat. In my code i have:

```
Double value = 1.40;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00########");
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

Now, with this code, theoritically, i should have:

> 1.40

but, when the value is formatted i have an output like this:

> 1.3999999762

Why does this happen? How can i resolve it? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Check this out: http://ideone.com/SiUO90

Comment: OK, I can't reproduce this.  What aren't you telling us?  Is this code exactly what you're running?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `Double value = 1.40F;` on the first line?

Comment: If you solved it, then you should post your solution here, for the benefit of any future users with a similar problem.

Comment: A similar code to what I wrote is contained in a function. I passed to this function a wrong parameter, a float instead of a double. That's why I had a wrong result. It's a my error, not a DecimalFormat's error. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of `DecimalFormat`, it is a problem of [the way binary float point numbers work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Certain numbers are not representable this way, so you get an approximation to them - like in your case.

Using `BigDecimal` is a possible solution.

Comment: There's rather more to it than that.  There are many `double` values that are much closer to `1.40` than `1.3999999762` is.

Comment: @DavidWallace 1.3999999762 is the correct number rounded to the 10th digit

Comment: No, it's not.  Doubles are accurate to far more significant digits than this.  This would be correct if this were a float, not a double.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, thanks, did not see that it was the german article. Fixed

Comment: @DavidWallace You are right, it is the correct number for float. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) directly. You may try like this:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    ((DecimalFormat) f).applyPattern("###,###,###.00########");
}
```

**[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wtmTTW)**

Using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is good alternative.

The Oracle docs says:

> To obtain a NumberFormat for a specific locale, including the default
>   locale, call one of NumberFormat's factory methods, such as
>   getInstance(). In general, **do not call the DecimalFormat
>   constructors directly**, since the NumberFormat factory methods may
>   return subclasses other than DecimalFormat.